# how can i alter the contents and log it in console in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using services in angular and pulling data from the URL :
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts  And rendering it on the browser in form of a table.
Next I want to perform an update operation to the contents in such a way that my posts[] gets updated and render it on console.
Any idea how to do it?

My post.component.ts

```
import { PostsService } from './../posts.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: any[];

  constructor( private service : PostsService ) { 

    this.service.getPosts().subscribe(response => {
  this.posts = response;
})
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

posts.component.html

```
    <table *ngFor="let post of posts" >
<tr><td>{{post.title}}</td>
<td>{{post.id}}</td>
<td>{{post.body}}</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the update to be triggered by an event such as a button click? Or do you just want to modify the results of the response before rendering them to the table?

Comment: You didn't tell us how you want these items to be updated.

Comment: there could be a button on the html which calls the update method and update the data of the row  which has been passed and then display on the console.

Answer (score 0):

> there could be a button on the html which calls the update method and
>   update the data of the row which has been passed and then display on
>   the console.

This is quite simple. Add the button in the html:

```
<table *ngFor="let post of posts" >
<tr><td>{{post.title}}</td>
<td>{{post.id}}</td>
<td>{{post.body}}</td></tr>
    </table>
<button (click)="updateData()">Update</button>
```

in the ts file, add the function:

```
public updateData(): void {
  this.posts.forEach(post => {
    post.body = "New custom body for each post";
  });

  console.log(this.posts);
}
```

This is just an example. Since you haven't tell us how do you want the data to be modified, I just assigned a new `body` to each entry.

> EDIT: Like when i click on the update button,the corresponding row
>   should become editable and once edited it should update the original
>   posts[] corresponding to that entry and display on console

I came up with this idea: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-shadow-sksf9

Basically you add a custom property to `posts` and set it to `false` by default:

```
interface Post {
  id: number;
  body: string;
  inEdit?: boolean;
}

posts: Post[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      body: "body 1",
      inEdit: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      body: "body 2",
      inEdit: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      body: "body 3",
      inEdit: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      body: "body 4",
      inEdit: false
    }
  ];
```

To add the custom property when you get the data from the API, you can do that:

```
public getData(): void {
  this.yourService.getData()
    .subscribe((response: Post[]) => {
      this.posts = response.map(post => {
        post.inEdit = false;
      };
    });
}
```

Then modifiy the html in order to use an `input` only when you're editing the row (after pressing a button):

```
<table *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index">
  <tr>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!post.inEdit">
      <td>{{post.id}}</td>
      <td class="long-body">
        {{post.body}}
      </td>
      <button (click)="post.inEdit = !post.inEdit">
        Edit me
      </button>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="post.inEdit">
      <td>{{post.id}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" #bodyValue [value]="post.body" />
      </td>
      <button *ngIf="post.inEdit" (click)="updateRow(i, bodyValue.value)">
        Save changes
      </button>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Finally, the `updateRow` function:

```
public updateRow(index: number, newBody: string): void {
    this.posts[index].body = newBody;
    this.posts[index].inEdit = false;

    console.table(this.posts[index]);
  }
```

Here's the little css I used in order to have the text in edit and not in edit the same width:

```
table {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.long-body,
input {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is that i am having a button in each row and when clicked it will call the update method defined in the ts file which should update the original posts[].

Comment: Like when i click on the update button,the corresponding row should become editable and once edited it should update the original posts[] corresponding to that entry and display on console.

Comment: That's a different thing, way much harder to do. I can come up with an idea if you let me some time.

Comment: meawhile i am trying to pass the  value of an like this below:<table *ngFor="let post of posts" >
       
<tr><td> <button (click)="updateData(post)">Update</button></td><td>{{post.title}}</td>
<td>{{post.id}}</td>
<td>{{post.body}}</td></tr>
    </table>

Comment: Please, have a look at the edited answer and let me know if it's all ok.

Comment: i got the logic but in my case i am drawing data from url .i.e post is getting updated by using an API call to the provided url.How can i add custom property to that?

Comment: Updated my answer again. Since the property `inEdit` is not required (`?` means basically that) you should not have problems if you do the http call to update the data in the DB.

Comment: Can you tell me how InEdit is getting initialised?I mean to ask from where is it picking up initial data?

Comment: You assign the data using `this.posts = response;`  before doing that you can `.forEach` the response and add to every element the property. Remember to specify the type of `response` to be `Post[]` otherwise you'll get a typo.